# mne raw plot looks like vertical lines instead of the usual signal

Tags: python, eeg

I have a data from a single eeg channel. When I plot it with plt, it looks like a regular signal.
[image: plot of signal using plt]

However, when I'm trying to plot with mne raw object's method plot, it looks very strange, like vertical lines:
[image: plot of signal using mne raw object's method]

Does anyone know why it looks like that?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you solve it? How do I increase the scaling parameter? I know I am not supposed to ask questions but I can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`raw.plot(scalings="auto")`

find more at https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.viz.plot_raw.html

Comment: Hello Towsif Ahamed Labib and welcome to DSP SE. I suggest you add some more information to your answer. You should explain your code and make it at least a complete answer which someone can use to solve their problem. I suggest you put together a simple solution and explain (at least briefly) what the link you posted contains. This will help the person who posted the question (OP) to solve their problem and will act as future reference to people who may have the same (or similar) problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need change the scalings parameter. In this case, you need increase it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while. Try setting the scaling parameter to `auto`.